# Network Simulator for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, software-recommendation

I'm looking for good open-source network simulator programs which I can use on my Ubuntu 12.04

I know about Cisco-packet tracer and I used it in my 32 bit machine earlier. But now my 64 bit machine is not able to install it. (I know I can use wine as well!!!).

GNS3 is good but it is not free I think.

So are there any other network simulators that I can use on my Ubuntu system.

PS Can anyone please also clarify as when I used packet tracer the routers etc were of Cisco definitely but are there any network simulatotors where one can simulate network on other manufacturers hardware as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually GNS3 is an open source software. Also Dynamips (the core of GNS3) is open source. The problem with them is that you need to have original IOS images to emulate routers (or IPS or firewalls). You can also emulate JunOs.

GNS3 gives also the possibility to add virtual machines (from VirtualBox or Qemu) to the topology. You can still play a bit with GNS3 emulating open source network appliances such as: OpenWRT(https://openwrt.org/), Vyatta core (http://www.vyatta.org/node/6757), Openvswitch(http://openvswitch.org/), pfSense (http://www.pfsense.org/). Just pay attention to the resources needed to emulate a complex network.

Another good software to emulate networks is ns (http://www.nsnam.org/).

Source: [Network Simulator for Ubuntu 12.04](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/network-simulator-for-ubuntu-12-04/3288?noredirect=1#comment5015_3288)